# Where I can get google-services.json without migrating to Firebase?

Tags: android, google-maps, firebase

I have an existing project with Maps Api enabled in Google Cloud Console.
I want to get `google-services.json` file for that project, but the old link to the page with download leads to the firebase main page. 
i.e.: https://developers.google.com/mobile/add?platform=android&cntapi=signin&cnturl=https:%2F%2Fdevelopers.google.com%2Fidentity%2Fsign-in%2Fandroid%2Fsign-in%3Fconfigured%3Dtrue&cntlbl=Continue%20Adding%20Sign-In

I have a requirement to ***not use*** firebase for now, so how can I get this file without adding my project to firebase?